# How do I Reduce in different directions?

Tags: r, dataframe, zoo

Suppose I have the following zoo objects:

```
fmt <- "%m/%d/%Y"
df1 <- data.frame(date=c('1/11/1999', '2/5/1999', '3/8/1999','4/5/1999','6/11/1999'), v1=c(1,2,3,4,5), v2=c(10,9,8,7,6))
df1$date <- as.Date(df1$date, format = fmt)
df1.zoo <- read.zoo(df1)

df2 <- data.frame(date=c('1/11/1999', '2/8/1999', '3/8/1999','4/5/1999','6/15/1999'), v1=c(1,2,3,4,5), v2=c(11,8,5,3,2))
df2$date <- as.Date(df2$date, format = fmt)
df2.zoo <- read.zoo(df2)

...
```

I would like to use something like Reduce(...) to have PER DAY:

1. sum of corresponding values in v1 and
2. diff of corresponding values in v2.

So the output I would expect here is:

```
dt       |     v1     |      v2
'1/11/1999'    2             -1
'2/5/1999'     2             9
'2/8/1999'     2             -8
...
```

> NOTE: I would prefer a solution using zoo or base R.

Comment: In the output, is v1 =  df1.zoo$v1 + df2.zoo$v1 and v2 = df1.zoo$v2 - df2.zoo$v2?

Comment: Because I can't seem to make sense of your expected output

Comment: @StupidWolf: Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope I got you correct, you define a function that takes in 2 variables, and Reduce will work on that:

```
matrix_function=function(x,y)cbind(v1=x[,1]+y[,1],v2=x[,2]-y[,2])

library(zoo)
Reduce(matrix_function,list(df1.zoo,df2.zoo))

           v1 v2
1999-01-11  2 -1
1999-03-08  6  3
1999-04-05  8  4
```

We try it on 1000 dataframes, first we have a matrix with 1000 columns and 5 row values will will be taken by each data.frame in the list:

```
set.seed(100)
v1_matrix = matrix(runif(5000),nrow=5)
v2_matrix = matrix(runif(5000),nrow=5)

list_of_df = lapply(1:1000,function(i){
  fmt <- "%m/%d/%Y"
  df <- data.frame(
  date=c('1/11/1999', '2/5/1999', '3/8/1999','4/5/1999','6/11/1999'), 
  v1=v1_matrix[,i], v2=v2_matrix[,i])
  df$date <- as.Date(df$date, format = fmt)
  df.zoo <- read.zoo(df)
  df.zoo
})
```

We apply the function and Reduce:

```
res=Reduce(matrix_function,list_of_df)
```

The first column should be the rowSums of the first matrix:

```
res[,1] == rowSums(v1_matrix)
1999-01-11 1999-02-05 1999-03-08 1999-04-05 1999-06-11 
      TRUE       TRUE       TRUE       TRUE       TRUE
```

The second column should be the first column of the 2nd matrix, substracting the sum of the remaining column:

```
res[,2] == v2_matrix[,1]-rowSums(v2_matrix[,-1])
1999-01-11 1999-02-05 1999-03-08 1999-04-05 1999-06-11 
      TRUE       TRUE       TRUE       TRUE       TRUE
```

Comment: What if I have 1000 data.frame objects?

Comment: it works as long as you can get them into a list, but good point, let me try it out in my answer